# Change struct names from upper-case to lower-case using coccinelle

Tags: c, coccinelle

I am trying to use Coccinelle to update a large number of files with C code to the Linux coding styles, but I can't manage to change the struct names. I am using the following script:

```
@rule1 disable all@
type t;
@@
typedef struct {
...
} t;

@ script:python foo @
t_fixed;
var;
t << rule1.t;
@@
import re
def split_uppercase(s):
    return re.sub(r'([a-z-0-9])((?<![0-9]{4})[A-Z])',r'\1_\2',s).replace("_k_Hz", "_kHz").replace("_M_Hz", "_MHz").replace("d_B", "dB").lower()

print coccinelle.t
coccinelle.t_fixed = split_uppercase(t)
print coccinelle.t_fixed
coccinelle.var = cocci.make_type(t_fixed)
print var

@rule2 disable all@
type rule1.t;
type foo.var;
@@
+ var
- t
```

The desired result is to change:

```
typedef struct {
    char me;
    long you;
} strName;

int main (void) {
    strName *DeV;
    return 0;
}
```

To:

```
typedef struct {
    char me;
    long you;
} str_name;

int main (void) {
    str_name *DeV;
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
init_defs_builtins: /usr/lib/coccinelle/standard.h
----------------------------------------------------------------------- processing semantic patch file: structs_test.cocci with isos from:
/usr/lib/coccinelle/standard.iso
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

dependencies for script satisfied: HANDLING: test_basic.c dependencies
for rule rule1 satisfied:
     transformation info is empty dependencies for script satisfied: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 10, in
<module> AttributeError: Cocci instance has no attribute 'make_type'
while running simple python string: from coccinelle import *

import re def split_uppercase(s):
    return re.sub(r'([a-z-0-9])((?<![0-9]{4})[A-Z])',r'\1_\2',s).replace("_k_Hz",
"_kHz").replace("_M_Hz", "_MHz").replace("d_B", "dB").lower()

print coccinelle.t coccinelle.t_fixed = split_uppercase(t) print
coccinelle.t_fixed coccinelle.var = cocci.make_type(t_fixed) print var







: Failure in foo Fatal error: exception Yes_pycocci.Pycocciexception
```

I am sorry if the question is wrong.